# Can we create a combobox event that all comboboxes refer to?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have to use a preview text input event that I have to apply to all the comboboxes in my application.

example

```
 private void cmbClass_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
 {
    cmbClass.IsDropDownOpen = true;
 }
```

Is there anyway i can use a header(any possible way) so that i don't have to type the preview text input in all of my comboboxes (98 in total)?

Comment: Do all of the ComboBox's have the same Parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style in app.xaml. This will be applied to all the comboboxes of your application but if you want this in comboboxes of a particular window then write it in the tag `<Window.Resources>`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="key1" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

or

```
<Window.Resources>
   ...
</Window.Resources>
```

or

you can assign a common event to all comboboxes. Write this code in your .cs file and select all comboboxes and assign this event to PreviewTextInput event.

```
private void cmboxes_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to use the previewtextinput property when i use it in xaml

Comment: previewtextinput is not a property its an event.

Comment: thanks for correcting.But should i write a class?Or am i totally wrong?

Comment: @deception1: Mark as answer if that is what you want.